# Semantic roles in a sentence

Tags: grammatical-roles

Can someone explain me what a semantic role in a sentence is? From my understanding is it subject–verb–object relationship? Take this sentence:

> The Rhine River takes its source in Switzerland before flowing through Basel and Strasbourg in Alsace Lorraine.

Would the subject be the Rhine river, the verb takes and the object its source in Switzerland? Or would the object be its source in Switzerland before flowing through Basel and Strasbourg in Alsace Lorraine.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking us to diagram the sentence or are you asking what the definition of semantic role is?

Comment: How will it be if it is passivized as "Its source in Switzerland is taken by the Rhine River travels, before flowing through Basel....."? It doesn't sound that beautiful even when 'takes' is considered a transitive verb.  I think "...its source in Switzerland.... in the question functions as a adverbial.

Comment: Are you sure you want the two verbs *travels* and *takes* appearing side-by-side? It seems to me you want one or the other, but not both.

Comment: The definition of a semantic role and what are the semantic roles in my sentence.

Comment: River's don't ***take*** their source from anywhere. They ***have*** a source [wherever they start], or they ***run*** from the source to the sea or whatever.

Comment: Consider 'John hit Jill.' [Subject] [Verb {trans}] [{direct} Object], usually abbreviated to the **SVO** sentence-type. The **semantic roles** (aka **thematic relations**) (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation)) addressed in this sentence are [**_Sentient_ Agent**] (the lad John, the doer/culprit) and the [**Experiencer**] (poor Jill). If we passivise the sentence, 'Jill was hit by John', 'Jill' becomes the new subject but the girl Jill remains the experiencer. John remains the real-life agent, though 'John' is no longer the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Semantic roles relate to the "agent" — the do-er — and the "patient "— the, uh, do-ee. (Terms vary.) In the active voice, the subject is the agent, and the object is the patient. In the passive voice, the object is promoted to the subject position, but it remains the patient. (Your sentence is in the active voice. This particular sentence can't be made passive in any natural way.)

Answer (score 1):

## Sentence analysis

There already are good answers in the comments, and I concur that I am a bit unsure what you are looking for, but I’ll have a jab at it. Let us first analyse your sentence:

> The Rhine River takes its source in Switzerland before flowing through Basel and Strasbourg in Alsace Lorraine.

The subject of the sentence is ‘the Rhine River’; the verb ‘takes’ is transitive, and thus takes an object, which in the first part of the sentence is ‘its source’. The second part of the sentence is broken off by ‘before’, which I here understand as a conjunction.

> CONJUNCTION 
> 1 In advance of the time when.
> ‘they lived rough for four days before they were arrested’
> —Oxford Dictionary: [‘before’](https://www.lexico.com/definition/before)

This allows us to analyse the second sentence as keeping the subject from the first one (‘the Rhine River’). We can replace this with the pronoun ‘it’, understanding the second sentence as:

> […] before [it is] flowing […]

The verb ‘to be’ (ɔ: ‘is’) is intransitive; intransitive verbs do not take objects, but can take predicates. Predicates behave sort of like objects, but the verb functions more like an equals sign, hence:

> Bob is a blue boy →
> Bob = a blue boy →
> Bob [is the same as] a blue boy

In your sentence, there is no predicate after flowing, merely an adverbial phrase telling us where the flowing is taking place.

## Defining ‘semantic roles’

A semantic role is, according to the peer-reviewed encyclopaedia *Store norske leksikon*:

> ### semantisk rolle
>
> Semantisk rolle, en beskrivelse eller definisjon av et syntaktisk ledd og dets funksjon i en setning. De to vanligste rollene er *agens* og *patiens* (eller *tema*) som henholdsvis beskriver agenten eller utøveren av en setning (vanligvis, men ikke alltid subjektet) og den eller det som det blir gjort noe med (vanligvis det direkte objektet).
>
> ### semantic role
>
> Semantic role, a description or definition of a syntactic element and its function in a sentence. The two most common roles are *agens* and *patiens* (or *topos*) which respectively describe the agent or practitioner of a sentence (usually, but not always, the subject) and the one or the thing which something is acted upon (usually the direct object).

## Final answer

Thus, the semantic roles in your example sentence are performed by: in the first part ‘the Rhine River’ (agens – the agent) and ‘source’ (here it sort of is the patiens); and in the second part an unexpressed agens, ɔ: ‘it’.

Comment: A lot of the roles in the example sentence would be locatives, and of course since rivers are not alive their role as agent is evidence of some metaphorization.